# How to route all incoming/outgoing traffic to eht1 instead of eth0 on aws linux 2 instance

Tags: linux-networking, aws-ec2

I am new to the AWS Linux environment, I have added a new network interface (eth1) with my AWS Linux 2 instance. now I want to route all of my incoming and outgoing traffic through this interface(eth1) instead of eth0 which is the default network adopter.
thanks

Comment: There's no *default adapter*. There's a routing table. The routing table decides where packets go.

Comment: @vidarlo eth0 is the default adapter on the host that corresponds to the primary ENI created with the EC2.  In order to get to the routing table you see through the AWS console, the EC2 is configured by default to send traffic to the first reserved IP address in the subnet.